# Image attached to text

Tags: css

I have an image I want placed over some particular text. Thing is, this text is not always of the same length, which means the image is in different places depending on the text length. What options do I have to change for the image to be placed only over that particular  but also not move about when other text around it is of different length?

```html
<div>
  <br>
  <span class="bigSignature" v-if="report_info.accepted && report_info.accepted_by !== null">{{ memberById(report_info.accepted_by).callsign }}
          <img style="position:absolute;top:47%;left:82%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
          width:15%;height:auto;" src="https://imgur.com/blabla.png"/>
          </span>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
<button v-if="isAdmin" class="float-right" v-on:click="acceptRejectReport">{{ acceptButtonText }}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: please post some testable code, and also the style rule applied to the elements  (try adding "position:relative" to the span)

Comment: Position relative just moves other elements out of the way. Ideally I'd want to image to cover parts of text and not be inline.